# Break-down ApplicationELB metrics by host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-application-load-balancer

Is there a way to break down the metrics of a Load Balancer to show me the active connection count on every target of its target group? I can only seem to find a way to get the total number for the entire Load Balancer.
[Active Connection Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjrgi.png)

I've looked for metrics on the EC2 instances themselves and in the target groups but can't find a count for active sessions on each instance that is behind the load balancer.